# Regex to allow only a single slash but not multiple slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

[image]I am writing a regex to satisfy the following conditions
no capital letters,
no spaces, no underscores,
umlauts or special characters and no multiple slashes.

I have implemented this `/[^a-z\/{1}\s]/g` but still it allows more than one slash. Any idea what I am missing .

```
if(value.match(/[^a-z\/{1}\s]/g) ){
    console.log(invalid)
 }
```

1. these values should fail to pass a test

---

```
  SHOULDNOTMATCH
  some_
  über
  ässs
  schleißheim
  some?sd
  some/7asa+
  some one
  shouldnotmatche//
  dont'allow
  /home//some/where/
```

2. These values should pass a test

---

```
   home
   page
   thisshouldpass
   someothertext
```

Comment: Maybe test it out on https://regex101.com/ or similar websites. See what your regex actually matches here https://regex101.com/r/34U6Rz/1

Comment: @humble_barnacle I already used that tool , as seen from the attached picture. strings with // are not matched

Comment: @anubhava your suggestion does not match anything including accepted values  eg : 1. home
       2. thisshouldmatch
       3. page

Comment: ok then update question with accepted and not-accepted examples.

Comment: @anubhava thank you for your effort but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: [Check this working demo](https://regex101.com/r/JmVwN5/1)

Comment: @anubhava , thank you for your support . It works for me for my current test cases. Still trying more test cases to see where there's a loop hole . but can you please add a little explanation to your regex /^[a-z]+(?:\/[a-z]*)?$/gm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may consider this regex for your cases:

```
/^[a-z]+(?:\/[a-z]*)?$/igm
```

Which matches 1+ letters at the start i.e. `^[a-z]+` followed by an *optional* group: `(?:\/[a-z]*)?` which means match a `/` followed by 0 or more letters before end position.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JmVwN5/1)